# how to use Backbone.js with the Symfony framework and or Apache Thrift

Tags: javascript, symfony, backbone.js, thrift

I recently installed a web app which use `Symfony2` framework and `Apache Thrift`.

Now I would like to make backbone usable in `Symfony2` framework.

My question is about `Backbone.sync`.

1. How can I override/use `Backbone.sync` in order to get data from the server in a web app using `Symfony2` framework and/or `Apache Thrift` ?
2. Are there some tutorials on the web for do it? I just found this one [Symfony + Backbone.js for highly dynamic apps](http://sf.khepin.com/2011/11/symfony-backbone-js-for-highly-dynamic-apps/), but it doesn't say nothing about how to get data from the server.

Comment: well... you'd make a rest service in symfony2 and then access it through backbone...

Answer (score 5):

By default, Backbone.js and its sync method can work with REST APIs without any modification. So if you can create a web service with Symfony2 that can handle GET/POST/PUT/DELETE and return JSON, you should be good to go.

I'm not terribly familiar with Symfony, but for a basic REST API, you'll need to define your URL routes (e.g. "www.yourdomain.com/api/items"), and then create methods to perform actions based on those routes (e.g. return records in JSON encoded format).

Here's a quick tutorial on creating a REST API with Symfony2: [Symfony2 REST](http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/symfony2-rest/)

Also, check out Wine Cellar tutorial on the [Backbone tutorial](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Tutorials,-blog-posts-and-example-sites) page.  It uses PHP Slim framework, but the backbone.js concepts will be exactly the same, because as long as you are using a basic REST API, backbone is back-end agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

Check this bundle https://github.com/gigo6000/DevtimeRafflerBundle it's a small simple app that includes some basic REST actions. This was created with https://github.com/gigo6000/DevtimeBackboneBundle